# React Native Android- App crashing in Vivo IQOO neo7 android14 on lunching the app

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.vivo.vspa.promotion.FrameRequestManager.(FrameRequestManager.java:54)
at android.view.VivoViewRootImplImpl.(VivoViewRootImplImpl.java:121)
at com.vivo.VivoSystemFrameworkFactoryImpl.createVivoViewRootImpl(VivoSystemFrameworkFactoryImpl.java:422)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:1172)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:423)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:164)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:431)
at org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:39)
at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:7927)
at org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen.show(SplashScreen.java:28)
at org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen.show(SplashScreen.java:52)
at com.truworth.wellnesscorner.ui.mainapp.HomeDashBoardActivity.onCreate(HomeDashBoardActivity.kt:117)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8937)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8901)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4246)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4418)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2820)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:328)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:9144)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:586)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:177)
at com.vivo.vspa.promotion.SlidingRecognitionInfo.getSlideRecognitionMode(SlidingRecognitionInfo.java:223)
at com.vivo.vspa.promotion.SlidingRecognitionInfo.setComponentCallbacks(SlidingRecognitionInfo.java:608)
at com.vivo.vspa.promotion.SlidingRecognitionInfo.(SlidingRecognitionInfo.java:122)

Updated the app all dependancies

Comment: edit question through code to code block

Comment: delete your question and read [how to ask normal question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)